# Plugin: allow_eecode - needed or not?

Tags: add-on, plugin, allow-eecode

Has the ability to use and parse `{exp}` tags within custom fields been absorbed into the EE system proper, or is the Allow EE Code plugin still needed to do this?

If it's still needed, might you be able to point to where it is? EL appears to have moved the download page.

Comment: See [this answer](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/405/ee-code-within-channel-entries#answer-411) for a good discussion on why it's a good idea to be careful using this plugin on site's edited by end users/non devs, and some alternative solutions...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope - it's still an add-on. You can find it on [github](https://github.com/EllisLab/Allow-Eecode).

Comment: Oh wow, how long have Ellislab had their addons on github?  I believe that when I upgraded I looked long and hard for a few of their plugins and finally translated them myself.

Comment: They have been there since the 20th August this year, 2011 for reference.